# Newsletter "Love this Site" header graphic still in English

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization, newsletter, international-sites

On https://ja.stackoverflow.com/ and possibly others (although I couldn't coax ru or pt into showing me this ad), the newsletter ad header is still in English:

[image]

The background image is [`cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/newsletter-ad.png`](http://cdn.sstatic.net/beta/img/newsletter-ad.png). While the other sidebar ads are also in English (understandable), it looks like there is intent to translate the newsletter one; language-specific background images should probably be made.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any reason to keep this banner title in graphic. Using "envelope" image only + text available via Transifex would be much better solution than creating a separate image for each localized site.

**Update:**

This string is translatable now in Transifex. Key is `90d0b739a13a0b5e9f33391811ecda8b`. Current look in English:

> [image: love in English]

Example view in Russian from rusSE, i.e. the text is translatable now:

> [image: love in Russian]

Hence the bug report should be tagged as completed.